# Using Codeigniter with SFTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, sftp

I want to access CodeIgniter system folder on another server securely via SFTP. I was able to connect to the server but the path to application and system folder could not be read in the index.php file on my local server.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your application folder path like this :

```
 $application_folder = "/Path/to/your/application";
```

Answer (score 1):

It usually resides in the `application` folder. See [their website](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html) or this [tutorial](http://blog.codeonion.com/2015/08/29/tutorial-2-codeigniter-3-0-1-understanding-application-folder-structure/) for further information.

Comment: Sorry I did not ask the question very clearly. The fact is that i have 2 servers, one contains the application folder and system folder while the other has the index.php and assets. All I need is the way of making the index.php communicate with the app and system folders on the other server via sftp. Thanks